# Use UIGestureRecognizer to get the UIabel text of UIview

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4, xcode9

I want to obtain the value of text of UILabel (label) of UIview (uiViews) using UIGestureRecognizer.

However, in my code I get an error.

Please tell me the correct code.

```
func test(){
    let uiViews = uiView.instance()//xib instance
    uiViews.label.text = "Yeah"
    self.addSubview(uiViews)
    uiViews.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapped.selected(_:))))
}

@objc func tapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print(sender.label.text) //Value of type 'UITapGestureRecognizer' has no member 'label'
}

//Error
Value of type 'UITapGestureRecognizer' has no member 'label'
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sender is UITapGestureRecognizer, it has a property called `view` that is the view being tapped. Use `(sender.view as? uiView)?.label?.text` to interact with the uiView/label.

Comment: This is a pretty common situation. The system frameworks are written so their methods pass you objects of a non-specific type like UIView, or even `Any`. You then need to cast the parameter to the specific type you're expecting.